# PyQt5: QCalendarWidget reset font of a de-selected date

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qcalendarwidget

I've created a calendar widget with its styleSheet, current date text format and set up date selection via .clicked function.

```
#setting up calendar
self.dateWidget = QCalendarWidget()

#setting up current date font format (on the app start)
self.painter = QTextCharFormat()
self.painter.setFont(QFont("Times", 20, 200))
self.dateWidget.setDateTextFormat(self.dateWidget.selectedDate(), self.painter)
    
#selecting current date on the app start, then connecting event for changing the date on click.
self.date = self.dateWidget.selectedDate()                      
self.dateWidget.clicked[QDate].connect(self.ChooseDate)

def ChooseDate(self, clicked=""):
    self.dateWidget.setDateTextFormat(clicked, self.painter)
    self.date = arrow.get(clicked.year(), clicked.month(), clicked.day())
    print(f'{self.date}: {self.time}')
```

When some date is clicked, its font gets modified.

**But when another date is clicked, the previous date's font stays modified. How do I reset the font of a de-selected (previous) date back to default - at the same time leaving the font of the TODAY date (which style is applied on app start) the same (increased)?**

[image]

*Pic.1 - Current date, selected on app start.*

[image]

*Pic.2 - Some date clicked. TODAY date (22nd) must stay as it is.*

[image]

*Pic.3 - Another date clicked. TODAY date (22nd) must stay as it is, but 24th must be reset to default.*

Comment: Just keep track of the *previous* selected date, and reset it only if it's not the current date. To reset the format, use a new QTextCharFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to clear the current formatting by setting a null date:

```
    self.painter = QTextCharFormat()
    self.painter.setFont(QFont("Times", 20, 200))
    self.dateWidget.clicked[QDate].connect(self.ChooseDate)
    self.ChooseDate()

def ChooseDate(self, clicked=None):
    # clear the current formatting first
    self.dateWidget.setDateTextFormat(QDate(), self.painter)
    # then reset the current and selected dates
    self.dateWidget.setDateTextFormat(QDate.currentDate(), self.painter)
    if clicked is not None:
        self.dateWidget.setDateTextFormat(clicked, self.painter)
        self.date = arrow.get(clicked.year(), clicked.month(), clicked.day())
        print(f'{self.date}: {self.time}')
    else:
        self.date = QDate.currentDate()
```

Comment: Yes, it works just as must be. Thank you very much!